# Highlight HTML and JavaScript in the same file in eclipse?

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

I'm new to eclipse and I'm trying to edit a .html file that contains both html and JavaScript. I've installed the Web Page Editor and JavaScript Development Tools add-ons but nothing seems to be working. It will (obviously) highlight the html but getting it to highlight the JavaScript inside the

`<script> .... </script>` tags is proving to be a challenge.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could either code in separate files or use notepad++ or something besides eclipse

Answer (score 1):

The solution here http://www.elvenware.com/charlie/development/web/HtmlGuide/EclipseWebDevelopment.html worked for me. I did **not** use the plugin - I followed the "Alternative" instructions:

Choose "Help | Install New Software" from the Eclipse menu. Select the following in the "Work With" drop down:

Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

Scroll to the bottom to the "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development" section.

Choose:

- Eclipse Web Developer Tools
- JavaScript Developer Tools
- Web Page

Answer (score 0):

Did you try going to Window>Preferences, select "Javascript>Editor>Syntax Coloring" from the list on the left. And see if the colors are set to your liking. 
Also check what you project is set as. Maybe it is interpreted as another language.

Hope this helps.